# Detect when two edges make a "inner" angle or an "outer" angle

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces

So, given three points, a direction of movement and the side of the movement, find out the "external" or "internal" angle value.

[image: Description]

In the left pic, I'm above the red line, moving from edge 1 to edge 2. The "external" angle (in orange) needs to be found.

In the right pic, I'm above the red line, moving from edge 1 to edge 2. The "internal" angle (in orange) needs to be found.

The info I have:
- the x and y values of the points
- the direction of the movement
- the direction of the lines (they are defined in a clockwise order)

This is killing me. Thanks.

Oh, and sorry about the "external" and "internal" names. I really don't know the definition of these.

I have to find the answer in all cases, here some more examples:
[image]

We could use p1, p2 and p3. p1 being the first point of the movement, p2 is the middle and p3 is the final one. In all cases this applies.

---

### EDIT: Some more cases

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_1=(x_1,y_1),\;P_2=(x_2,y_2),\;P_3=(x_3,y_3)$. Then we have two vectors (arrows, if you like):

$${\bf v_1} = \overrightarrow{P_1P_2} = (x_2-x_1,\; y_2-y_1) \\
{\bf v_2} = \overrightarrow{P_2P_3} = (x_3-x_2,\; y_3-y_2).$$

The angle, $\theta$, between them is found via their dot product:

$$\theta_0 = \cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{{\bf v_1}\cdot {\bf v_2}}{\|{\bf v_1}\|\;\|{\bf v_2}\|} \right).$$

This gives a value $\theta_0\in [0,\pi]$ and it assumes that ${\bf v_2}$ starts at $P_1$ instead of at $P_2$, which we must adjust for.

We also need to consider whether, in moving from ${\bf v_1}$ to ${\bf v_2}$, we are "turning left" or "turning right". We can determine this by using the cross product of these two vectors.

If we are turning left, the cross product vector ${\bf v_1}\times {\bf v_2}$ is in the positive $z$ direction, and if we are turning right it is in the negative $z$ direction.

The $z$-coordinate, $z_c$, of this cross product is:

$$z_c = (x_2-x_1)(y_3-y_2) - (x_3-x_2)(y_2-y_1).$$

Finally, we consider the side of the lines we move on. As we move along from $P_1$ to $P_2$ to $P_3$ this could be either the left or the right side of the lines. In the new examples provided, we are on the left in rows $1$ and $4$. we are on the right in rows $2$ and $3$.
So you could equate "being on the left of the lines" with either:

- moving left on the upper side, or
- moving right on the lower side.

And you could equate "being on the right of the lines" with either:

- moving left on the lower side, or
- moving right on the upper side.

So, putting this all together, we have the required angle, $\theta_1$, as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}
&& \text{if $\theta_0 = 0$ then $\qquad\theta_1 = \pi$} \\
&& \text{else if $\theta_0 = \pi$ then $\qquad\theta_1 = 0$} \\
&& \text{else if we are on the LEFT of the lines and $z_c \gt 0$ then $\qquad\theta_1 = \pi - \theta_0$} \\
&& \text{else if we are on the LEFT of the lines and $z_c \lt 0$ then $\qquad\theta_1 = \pi + \theta_0$} \\
&& \text{else if we are on the RIGHT of the lines and $z_c \gt 0$ then $\qquad\theta_1 = \pi + \theta_0$} \\
&& \text{else if we are on the RIGHT of the lines and $z_c \lt 0$ then $\qquad\theta_1 = \pi - \theta_0$}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks man. Unfortunately, this algorithm is not working in my case. If I move against some vertex walking right and walking left, I get different values, and the values should be the same.

I'm going to edit my post and use another picture if you think it could help.

Comment: @RamonAmorim Hi... Thanks for the extra examples. I think I understand it more fully now. I've revised my answer accordingly and I hope it works for you. Let me know if any problem.

Comment: Man, I got a feeling that we are almost there. Sorry for having trouble in explaining my issue. English is not my native language and my math vocabulary is very (VERY) limited. I'll try to explain in greater detail in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fm_YsmFLeZA). Hope it helps.

Comment: @RamonAmorim Thanks for the video. In my answer, "we are on the LEFT of the lines" means "we are pressing the right arrow". And "we are on the RIGHT of the lines" means "we are pressing the left arrow". In the video, I don't understand why you aren't allowed to go past an angle <180. Do you mean that is where the program fails? Or is this a rule of the game? (Your images show <180 and >180 but they it seems both are allowed.) If it's still wrong can you show an example and show me the angle the program gives you (both $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$) and also what the angle should be (roughly)?

Comment: You are right. In fact, my code was broken and I didn't notice it. The code you provided above works in every case and it's wonderful. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @RamonAmorim No problem. I'm glad it works! :)